# active reports and ssrs comparison

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, activereports

I want to take data from a SQL server ans show it in to the user. I have to update the UI as the user's requirement. what are the advantages and disadvantages of both reporting tool?. Also anyone know about the licensing cost for both?

Comment: SSRS is for free while you've SQL server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alias,

both reporting tools are very similar in terms of features.  ActiveReports has royalty free distribution and is licensed per developer.  the cost ranges from $799-$1599 per developer.

If you are asking about SSRS server, then it is included as part of the SQL server license, however read the license carefully.   You cannot install SSRS on a separate server from SQL Server, it requires IIS, both of these items add pressure on your DB installation, which could be an issue in the future.  You would need another SQL server license in order to deploy them separately.

I would suggest that you download and try them and see which one is easier and would fit your needs better and review the licensing based on your requirements.

disclaimer - I work for Grapecity maker of ActiveReports.

Comment: Not sure I believe you: I would think if you work for the company then you would know that it's "GrapeCity" and not "Grapecity"...

Comment: I not only work for "GrapeCity" but I am also the founder of Data Dynamics, the original creator of ActiveReports.     Issam Elbaytam